# Mock response cookies in .NET 6 uisng Moq

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, moq

I am migrating unit tests from .NET framework to .NET 6. How can I mock the below code?

```
var response = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
response.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
```

Here's a example of a unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest()
{
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponse>();
    response.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
    response.Setup(r => r.Headers).Returns(new HeaderDictionary());

    var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
    var stringCol = new QueryString();
    stringCol.Add("login", "error");
    request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(stringCol);
    var cookies = new RequestCookieCollection();
    cookies.Add("sampleCookieKey", "sampleCookieValue");
    request.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
    
    var context = new Mock<HttpContext>();
    context.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(c => c.Response).Returns(response.Object);

    var ctrl = new SampleController("blah blah");
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), new ControllerActionDescriptor());
    ctrl.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(actionContext);

    var res = ctrl.SendTemplate("123", "true", _encryptor.Encrypt(user).Token);
    Assert.IsNotNull(res);
    Assert.IsTrue(res is EmptyResult);
}
```

I have updated the Request cookies using RequestCookieCollection() object. But for response similar object is not available.

Comment: I don't think that [HttpResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse) exists in .NET 6.

Comment: So, what can else can be done.

Comment: You'll have to start figuring out what will replace `HttpResponse`. [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage) might be a candidate, but it doesn't have a `Cookies` property, so you'll need to figure out what to do instead. Since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, I can't suggest more than that.

Comment: Could you please share with us the to-be-tested code as well?

Comment: updated question with a sample unit test.